# MATLAB Gui, text-box value on buttonpress without GUIDE

Tags: matlab, matlab-gui

I have a certain GUI built without GUIDE, just plain old uicontrols and I've gotten everything to work properly so far. However I want to, upon a button press grab the value in a text-box (edit) and store it into a variable fi.

Basically the code in question;

```
c2 = uicontrol(f,'Style', 'pushbutton','String','Rotation','Callback', 
@rotation);
s1 = uicontrol(f,'Style', 'edit');

function rotation(src,event)
   load 'BatMan.mat' X
   fi = %This is the value I want to have the value as the edit box.
   subplot(2,2,1)
   PlotFigure(X)
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest is to get `rotation` to know about `s1` through an input argument:

```
c2 = uicontrol(f,'Style', 'pushbutton','String','Rotation');
s1 = uicontrol(f,'Style', 'edit');
set(c2,'Callback',@(src,event)rotation(s1,src,event));

function rotation(s1,src,event)
   load 'BatMan.mat' X
   fi = get(s1,'String');
   subplot(2,2,1)
   PlotFigure(X)
end
```

Here, we set the callback for `c2` to be an anonymous function with the right signature (2 input arguments), and which calls `rotation` with `s1` as an additional argument. The callback now has the handle `s1` embedded in it.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, however I'm getting an error using the get method; Cannot find 'get' method for matlab.ui.eventdata.ActionData class.

Comment: @AntonHagelberg: That means that you still have `@rotation` as a callback function somewhere. Make sure you set the callback as I show here.

Comment: Can't thank you enough! I found this https://se.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/44462-trouble-storing-a-value-in-an-edit-box-in-a-gui-using-uicontrol and started trying to rebuild my entire GUI in this fashion instead but quickly realized it was a rough bit. This fixed my issues completely and I feel like I got a better understanding for using uicontrols in matlab :)